# rendere form with select django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a django form generated by a model.

```
class Manager(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    birth_date = models.DateField()
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    region_of_residence = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city_of_residence = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    common_of_redidence = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address_of_residence = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    zip_of_residence = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

i've created a form to overwrite some fields and add other one in this way:

```
class ManagerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    gender = forms.ChoiceField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    verify_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        model = Manager
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'gender', 'birth_date', 
'phone_number', 'region_of_residence', 'city_of_residence',
              'common_of_redidence', 'address_of_residence', 
'zip_of_residence', 'username', 'email', 'password',)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(ManagerForm, self).clean()
        password = cleaned_data.get("password")
        verify_password = cleaned_data.get("verify_password")

        if password != verify_password:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                "password and verify_password does not match"
            )
```

I've put my choice into an external file and they are:

```
GENDER_CHOICES = [
    _('Non specificato'),
    _('Uomo'),
    _('Donna')
]
```

now i've would like to render my form with a simple for statement

```
{% for field in form %}{% render_field field class="form-control" %}.
```

But i receive the follow error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

how can i render correctly these fields?

Comment: You have a syntax error, an extra bracket: `{% for field in form %}{*{*%`

Comment: in the source code there isn't, it's a typo

Answer (score 2):

CHOICES needs to be a list of 2--tuples consisting of the db value and the display value. For instance:

```
GENDER_CHOICES = [
    ("N", _('Non specificato')),
    ("U", _('Uomo')),
    ("D", _('Donna'))
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just render the form with:

`{{ form }}`